# Numpy functionality for determining the mean of a set of indices in a 3-dimensional matrix

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matrix

I have a 3d matrix representation of an image, so a (600, 800, 3) matrix. Currently, I'm using two for loops to iterate over the entire image to access each pixel value in order to calculate the mean value of each index (each index corresponds to an RGB value). This seems very tedious though. Is there a faster way using numpy functions to calculate the mean for all of these values? (I understand cv2 uploads images in BGR, and am converting it to RGB). Below is the current loop I'm using for calculating the means of the R, G, and B values.

Looking through the documentation for numpy.mean, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html
It looks like you can provide which axis to take the mean of when its a 2D matrix, but how can you apply this to a 3d matrix? Thanks.

```
img_RGB = cv2.imread('../data/source1.png')

meanOfImageIndex0 = 0 
meanOfImageIndex1 = 0 
meanOfImageIndex2 = 0 

for i in range(0 to len(img_RGB)):
    for j in range(0 to len(img_RGB[0])):
        meanOfImageIndex0 += img_RGB[i][j][0]
        meanOfImageIndex1 += img_RGB[i][j][1] 
        meanOfImageIndex2 += img_RGB[i][j][2] 

meanOfImageIndex0 = meanOfImageIndex0 / (len(img_RGB) * (len(img_RGB[0]))
meanOfImageIndex1 = meanOfImageIndex1 / (len(img_RGB) * (len(img_RGB[0]))
meanOfImageIndex2 = meanOfImageIndex2 / (len(img_RGB) * (len(img_RGB[0]))
```

Comment: Whether the pixels are ordered BGR, RGB won't make any difference to the mean as it is just sum of pixels divided by number of pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after reading through https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html
It looks like I could use

```
img_RGB = cv2.imread('../data/source1.png')

meanOfImageIndex0 = np.mean(img_RGB[:,:,0]) 
meanOfImageIndex1 = np.mean(img_RGB[:,:,1]) 
meanOfImageIndex2 = np.mean(img_RGB[:,:,2])
```

I think it is the numpy slicing syntax that I was/am a little fuzzy on